# NSDecimalNumber problems when parse a json url

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cocoa

When I run the Url i have a -[NSDecimalNumber length] problem. Please assist me.

```
@try {
responseData = [NSMutableData data];
NSString *urlRequest =[NSString stringWithFormat:MobileAdURL,pStrIdentity];

NSString *pStrLegalURLString =[urlRequest stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  //Or your String Encoding;
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pStrLegalURLString]];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

} @catch (NSException *exception) {
NSLog(@"Exception Error %@",exception);
} @finally {

}
```

After execute these above line this decimal number problem will show.

```
-[NSDecimalNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a79b950
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't see how that code can lead to that exception.  I think the issue lies elsewhere (for example in the delegate methods).

Comment: How do you said the problem in delegate method.

Comment: Because the code you posted cannot cause the exception.  Therefore I reckon it's within the processing of the received data.  Add an exception breakpoint to find out exactly where it's occurring and edit your question with the correct code.

Comment: Jee I was checked. After this line {[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self]} App will be crossed. I didnt get exception error also. I am using try catch method also jee. What you expect from me. I cant give URL because this is secured URL.

Comment: I expect you to find out exactly where the exception is being raised.

Comment: Jee check my question now. I was mentioned exception.

Comment: Open the Breakpoint Navigator and click the little plus sign ('+') in the bottom left corner and select "Add Exception Breakpoint". Then Xcode will break on the line of code that threw the exception.

Comment: I add already Exception Breakpoint. But xCode could not find out the error. And also the errors goes to main page. What can do..